# Why is my Controller being passed a UserManager which is Disposed?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

When i set a breakpoint in the constructor of this controller, I'm seeing a System.ObjectDisposedException from userManager.Users .  Why might .NET be giving me a disposed UserManager?  I have other controllers that seem to be set up the same way and their UserManagers work fine (this one dies when it calls GetUserAsync)

```
[RequireHttps]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RegionService _regionService;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RegionService regionService, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _regionService = regionService;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HomeController>();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

        ...
    }
```

...and i shouldn't be accessing a database in Home/Index; I'll change that afterward

***Edit:*** This is how services are being configured:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
        services.AddTransient<RegionService>();

        // require SSL
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });
    }
```

Comment: How are your services set up?

Comment: @NateBarbettini  in the Startup.cs ConfigureServices method?

Comment: @NateBarbettini there's nothing specifically setting up a UserManager from what I can see (I'm new at ASP.NET)

Comment: Can you post your ConfigureServices method?

Comment: @NateBarbettini  Ok, I just added it to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the constructor of a class I created called RegionService

```
    public RegionService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (var context = serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>())
        {
             ...
        }
    }
```

The 'using' statement causes 'context' to be disposed after it's done with that block of code.  I should have just been making a new instance of the DbContext that can be disposed:

```
public RegionService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(
            serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>()))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```